# Qt Creator custom split view settings for edit and debug

Tags: ide, qt-creator

Is it possible to have different split settings for Edit and Debug mode in Qt Creator?

I am:

- using two monitors
- splitting the editor vertically
- align the splits onto the edge between monitors

Now when I switch do debugging mode:

- the variable column gets squeezed in
- my editor split edge is pushed away from the monitor edge

Can I somehow tell Qt Creator to remember each split?

(I couldn't find a setting for this inside the Options or the Window menu)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although it's not exactly the solution I was looking for, it somehow fits my purpose:

1. use QtCreator without splitting window
2. go: Window -> Open in new Window
3. repeat 2 as often as desired
4. place the new window(s) as you wish

This will offer a second/third editor window.
Now if you switch between Editor and Debug in the first window, the second won't care about this.

However, this only works in versions 2.8.0 or higher.

*Side note:*
It's not perfect yet: QtCreator is somewhat creative which window to use for Debugging - it's nearly always the window I'm not looking at ;-)

Comment: This is also useful for having the Design and Edit windows visible at the same time